# Словарь функций в python3

Tags: python-3.x

Пытаюсь битый час понять, почему следующий код:

```
def fun(val):
   print(val)

{1: fun(1), 2: fun(2), 3: fun(3)}[3]
```

работает следующим образом:

```
1
2
3
```

Кто может разъяснить, как сделать так, чтобы при обращении `{...}[3]` выдавалось значение 3.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел такое решение: внутри словаря не значения функций, а сами функции. В таком случае действительно все логично (*простите за убогий пример*)

```
def fun(val):
   print(val)

{1: fun, 2: fun, 3: fun}[3](3)
```